# Unwanted padding-top automatically added

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design, padding

I'm currently working on the responsiveness of my site and I'm having some troubles with a search + submit input in a sidebar. In this sidebar I have a main div displayed as a table and divided in 2 cells. The left cell is a text input field, the right cell is a submit button (actually an image that acts as a submit button). The first thing is that I can't get them aligned, the text input is always 3px under the img.

As you can see in this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/5pNF7/

there shouldn't be any grey pixels above the text input. I don't get why there's a 3px padding-top automatically added on this text input.
How do I get rid of this?

HTML:

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area clearfix">
    <div id="content" class="site-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin diam dui, bibendum nec porta ut, elementum id lacus</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-area">
        <div id="tertiary" class="sidebar-container">
            <div class="sidebar-inner">
                <div class="widget-area">
                    <aside id="search-2" class="widget widget_search">
                        <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="http://foo.com">
                            <label> <span class="screen-reader-text">Search:</span>

                                <input type="search" class="search-field" value="" name="s">
                            </label>
                            <input type="image" class="search-submit" alt="Search" src="http://localhost/test-elisium/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen-child/resources/search-icon.png">
                        </form>
                    </aside>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.clearfix:after {
    content:".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.site-content {
    float: left;
    max-width: 55%;
    margin-right: 7%;
}
.sidebar-area {
    float: right;
    padding: 30px 3% 0 0;
    width:35%;
}
.widget {
    background-color: #999;
}
.widget input[type="search"] {
    width: 100%;
}
#search-2 form {
    display: table;
}
#search-2 .search-form label, .search-form .search-submit {
    display: table-cell;
}
.search-form .search-submit {
    width: 24px;
}
.screen-reader-text {
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
    position: absolute !important;
}
input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    border: 2px solid red;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this

```
#search-2 .search-form label, .search-form .search-submit {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5pNF7/2/

With vertical-align top, both your items will be align to the top, instead of one align at baseline and the other at top.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting form display:table and child element as display:table-cell, you can make use of float property.

```
#search-2 form {
    width: 100%;
}
#search-2 .search-form label
{
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
}
 .search-form .search-submit {
    float:left;
}
```

Also add clearfix class to form to get the full height of float elements.

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5pNF7/4/

Comment: Adding this float gives you a lot of whistespace, you would also have to add a div, max/min-width